# Select by certain digits after the decimal point of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like:

```
id  |  firstNumber  |  secondNumber
1   |    10.1234    |    15.3321
2   |    105.338    |    185.9921
3   |    10.1255    |    15.3368
4   |    50.5050    |    99.99
5   |    10.12345   |    17.3677
```

**Numbers are stored as Double

Assume I am given an input for 2 numbers: for example 10.123343 and 15.3335344 to compare with.

How to select all rows that have the same number up to a certain digit after the decimal point? And how to do that for 2 columns together? In my example, if I want numbers with accuracy of 2 digits after the point for both numbers (`firstNumber` and `secondNumber`), I should get rows 1 and 3.

Comment: You want all rows which match *any* other row up to a given precision?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot, assuming there is an input of numbers. for example if my input is 10.125666 and 15.33838

Answer (score 1):

With `floor(number)` you get the the integer part of a decimal number 
and with `floor(100 * number)` you get the part of the decimal number that you need to compare for the equality up to 2 decimal digits:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where 
    floor(100 * t.firstnumber) = floor(100 * 10.125666)
    and
    floor(100 * t.secondnumber) = floor(100 * 15.33838)
```

The same can be achieved with `truncate()`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where 
    truncate(t.firstnumber, 2) = truncate(10.125666, 2)
    and
    truncate(t.secondnumber, 2) = truncate(15.33838, 2)
```

Comment: What about using LIKE? Can that work as well? Assuming I can first extract the numbers with 2 digits after the point (using PHP or any other language)?

Comment: LIKE is a string comparison operator https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like, so first you have to convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

Given the clarification from the comments, it sounds like you want something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROUND(firstNumber, 2) = 10.12 AND ROUND(secondNumber, 2) = 15.33;
```

If you want numbers to match based on truncation instead of rounding you can use `FLOOR` as outlined in [forpas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54064902/2462437).

Comment: But the problem with round is that if for example the given number will be 10.1299 it will be 10.13, no? thus is won't match 10.12

Comment: In that case you'd use FLOOR rather than ROUND.  It depends on what you want.

Comment: What about using LIKE? Can that work as well? Assuming I can first extract the numbers with 2 digits after the point (using PHP or any other language)?

Comment: You can convert to a string, but it will be slower.  To be fair, though, FLOOR or ROUND will also be slower than optimal if there is an index on firstNumber and secondNumber.  In that case you'd want something like 

`WHERE firstNumber >= 10.12 AND firstNumber < 10.13 AND ...`